# error spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

i'm working in spring batch

```
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

        ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
        context.putString("resourceFileName", file.getFilePath());
        System.out.println("display resource path : ");
        System.out.println(context.get("resourceFileName"));

    }
```

this line works successfully i got the right path 
     `System.out.println(context.get("resourceFileName"));`

in the xml item reader i tried to get this resource like this

```
<property name="resource" value="file:#{stepExecutionContext['resourceFileName']}" />
```

but i got this error :

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Resource must not be null.
znd sometimes this error
Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode)

Comment: You are creating a new `ExecutionContext` why should it then be available to the `ExecutionContext` that is part to the `StepExecution`? The context is gone after the `beforeStep` method has executed.

Comment: i want to validate the filename before reading the content , i tried to put the same code in this methode befor read but i get this error Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode) without displaying the name of file in the console !!

Comment: Read my comment... You are creating a new `ExecutionContext` put stuff in it and expect that to be available outside of that method. As stated that isn't going to work. You have to use the `ExcutionContext` from the `StepExecution` NOT create a new one. Also imho you should be validating before starting the job and not while running the job.

Comment: Okey thank you  i'm gonna try with JobExecutionListener , please tell me how can i put the name of file in the context correctly and pass it to resource property

Comment: i have a liste of files in one folder , i must validate each file before reading , i have a new problm , the last file saved in the context not all files !

Comment: @M.Deinum is right about `ExecutionContext` lifecycle; what you are trying to do is incorrect; seems you don't fully understand how SB works.
Read official doc again and/or do some pratice with tutorials around the net.